# Where can I see all Google Cloud resources I have to pay for?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

During the last days, I've played around with gcloud, Google Compute Engine and Google Container Engine in different projects. Now I'm not sure if I stopped/deleted all resources correctly. I can see on https://console.developers.google.com/project that two of my projects generated costs in April, but cannot dive any deeper from there.

Is there a way to see all the items (of one of or all of my projects) that are currently creating costs?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at https://console.developers.google.com/billing/unbilledinvoice to see current charges that have not yet been billed.